# JAXB: Generate list of annotations on class

Tags: java, reflection, jaxb, annotations

Given the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElement("SubElement")
    public String subElement;
}
```

I'd like to recover all the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` annotations at both the field and class levels at runtime.  I know I can do so using Java's reflection API.  Does JAXB itself provide a way to collect these annotations?

Comment: You'll have no choice other than scanning the class method by method and field by field. Do you need to scan a given class only? If so, the code is simple enough using Java refelction's API. If you need to scan the whole classpath, using an external lib (built on top of Java's reflection API) is simpler. What is it gonna be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **`getAllAnnotationsOfPackage()`** does the trick.

It gets all annotations for a given `AnnotatedElement` (such as `Class`, `Method` and `Field`) that belong to the `annotationsPackage` package:

```
public static List<Annotation> getAllAnnotationsOfPackage(AnnotatedElement
                                   annotatedElement, String annotationsPackage) {
    Annotation[] as = annotatedElement.getAnnotations();
    List<Annotation> asList = new LinkedList<Annotation>();
    for (int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        if (as[i].annotationType().getPackage().getName()
                                               .startsWith(annotationsPackage)) {
            asList.add(as[i]);
        }
    }
    return asList;
}
```

Here's a working code (paste it on a GetAnnotationsOfPackage.java file) that **goes through all methods and fields of a given class and gets all annotations** of the given package:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class GetAnnotationsOfPackage {

    @XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Root {
        @XmlElement(name="SubElement")
        public String subElement;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Annotation> as = getAnnotationsOfPackage(Root.class, "javax.xml.bind.annotation");
        for (Annotation annotation : as) {
            System.out.println(annotation.annotationType().getName());
        }
    }

    public static List<Annotation> getAnnotationsOfPackage(Class<?> classToCheck, String annotationsPackage) {
        List<Annotation> annotationsList = getAllAnnotationsOfPackage(classToCheck, annotationsPackage);
        Method[] ms = classToCheck.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < ms.length; i++) {
            annotationsList.addAll(getAllAnnotationsOfPackage(ms[i], annotationsPackage));
        }
        Field[] fs = classToCheck.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) {
            annotationsList.addAll(getAllAnnotationsOfPackage(fs[i], annotationsPackage));
        }
        return annotationsList;
    }

    public static List<Annotation> getAllAnnotationsOfPackage(AnnotatedElement annotatedElement, String annotationsPackage) {
        Annotation[] as = annotatedElement.getAnnotations();
        List<Annotation> asList = new LinkedList<Annotation>();
        for (int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
            if (as[i].annotationType().getPackage().getName().startsWith(annotationsPackage)) {
                asList.add(as[i]);
            }
        }
        return asList;
    }
}
```

The `main()` method is **getting all annotations from `"javax.xml.bind.annotation"`** of the `Root` class and **printing their names**. Here's the output:

```
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
```

Comment: The number of classes to scan is relatively small so this is an acceptable approach.  It still seems odd that though JAXB is doing this very thing somewhere, it does not expose it to library users.

Comment: This is too raw (what class is annotated with what) for the JAXB spec to provide. If there was something near this, would be something more abstract like "get the list of `XmlRootElement`s:  `jaxbContext.getXmlRootElements()`". The closest to that we have today is [JAXBContext#createJAXBIntrospector()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#createJAXBIntrospector()), but the [JAXBIntrospector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBIntrospector.html) utility is still far from what you needed.